# JavaScript Date function not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, date, firefox

I have this code and I run it in chrome

```
var time = new Date("2014-02-11 19:30:00" + ' UTC');
```

This gives me back exactly what I need, it transforms the date I'm passing to my local time. Even this one does the exact same thing

```
var time = new Date("2014-02-11T19:30:00");
```

The problem is that the first function is not working in Mozilla and the second one doesn't transform the date to my local timezone. I need to do the transformation in both explorers (actually in all of them) but it would be great for it to at least work in those two.

Comment: those two snips do NOT do the same thing unless you live in England... Any browser supporting JSON will correctly parse the ISO format of "2014-02-13T18:33:27.872Z". you can break your date up into parts, or massage the string into ISO format before parsing.

Comment: Sorry but I copied and pasted on a new doc and they do exactly the same (at least in google chrome). I'm from Venezuela.

Comment: maybe since that particular input format is not standard your browser is quirking it out into a local date in an attempt to recover whatever info it can. GIGO. rewrite my first comment as "should not"...

Comment: Yeah as LShetty said the solution is to format my date to ISO format. Thanks, I really appreciate the info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on both:

Note: TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)

`new Date("1994-11-05T13:15:30Z")`

Comment: YES! This does work for both explorers and also makes the conversion to local timezone. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment in time. Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC.

```
Constructor

new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
```

It is the [definition of the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to use values 0-11 for the month field.

I believe that the constructor using a String is system-dependent (not to mention locale/timezone dependent) so you are probably better off using the constructor where you specify year/month/day as seperate parameters.

BTW, in Firefox,

```
  new Date("04/02/2008");
```

works fine for me - it will interpret slashes, but not hyphens. I think this proves my point that using a String to construct a Date object is problemsome. Use explicit values for month/day/year instead:

```
  new Date(2008, 3, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you, while this solve the problem of the function working in a explorer and not in other, it does not make the conversion to local timezone (which is what I really need).

Comment: the big advantage of parsing a standard date string is that timezone info is included with the numbers...

Comment: Oh I think I get what you are saying, and if it is what I think then the reason it doesn't work for me is because I am saving the date transformed to UTC on a server and then when I want to show it to the user I have to transform this UTC date to the user timezone. So the dateString I'm providing to the constructor is in UTC and I want it in localtimzone. Sorry for long explanation but I think that is what you meant.